# fit a form field to a background image

Tags: css

I'm having a bit of a problem solving this one:

I have a full screen image with a login box on it. I've seen plenty of ways to add an image to a form field, but I have to work the other way around. I have to fit the form field to the right place on the background image.

How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: I think you should also share your code, it will really help those who can solve your problem

Comment: There's nothing to share as yet. I have a background image with 'password' on it and a white box where the password should be typed. 
I have to figure out how to get it (= the form field) there.

Comment: or share some sample image of it, can't even figure it out man

Comment: I've added the background image. The form field with the password should be in the box.

Comment: What's your problem? Do you want to wrap your login form in a box and have it floating to the right?

Comment: I need to get the password within the box.

Comment: This is not a perfect way.. you need to remove that 'password' text and white box design from the background image and keep it as html element... because its difficult to fix the input box positions according to your current design in different screen sizes.

Comment: I know. This comes from the design department who know computers exist. To make graphics, that is. Landscape, Portrait, tablets, phones. Flies above these chaps. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```css
#myForm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px; /* wherever you want it */
  left: 400px; /* wherever you want it */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/800x300">
  <div id="myForm">
    <form>
      <label for="pw">Password</label>
      <input name="pw" type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!